# How to change the histogram bar width in displot

Tags: python, seaborn, histogram, displot

I'm using seaborn's displot to get stacked bar charts. Here is my code:

```
g = sns.displot(data=df, x='collection_year', hue='WB_Income group', multiple='stack',col="ena_species",col_wrap=6,facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': False})
```

and here is the output
[image]

How can I increase the width of the bars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- In this case, the x-axis is continuous, as is typical of a histogram.
- This issue can be resolved by setting `discrete=True` or setting `bins=` to match the number of unique values in `'year'`, which results in the x-ticks corresponding only to the values passed to the independent axis.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.3`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

#### Imports & Sample DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

# create sample data
np.random.seed(2022)
rows = 10000
data = {'year': np.random.choice(list(range(1985, 2025)), size=rows),
        'income': np.random.choice(['high', 'upper middle', 'lower middle', 'low'], size=rows),
        'species': np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase[:14]), size=rows)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display(df.head())
   year        income species
0  2013  upper middle       m
1  2009  lower middle       g
2  2003  lower middle       h
3  2009  upper middle       g
4  2001  lower middle       m
```

- The example plot, with large spaces between each bar, was only reproducible by setting `bins=160`, which is 4x the number of years from 1985 - 2025.
- There may be something in the `'year'` data that's not apparent in the OP.

```py
g = sns.displot(data=df, x='year', hue='income', multiple='stack', col="species", col_wrap=6, bins=160, facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': False})
```

[image]

- The issue can be resolved by setting `bins` to match the number of years in the data.

```py
g = sns.displot(data=df, x='year', hue='income', multiple='stack', col="species", col_wrap=6, bins=40, facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': False})
```

- The issue can also be resolved by removing `bins`, and setting `discrete=True`.

```py
g = sns.displot(data=df, x='year', hue='income', multiple='stack', col="species", col_wrap=6, discrete=True, facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': False})
```

[image]

- Setting `bins` to a number less than the number of unique values in `'year'` will produce a histogram where each bar encompasses multiple years.

```py
g = sns.displot(data=df, x='year', hue='income', multiple='stack', col="species", col_wrap=6, bins=20, facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': False})
```

[image]